# Unable to send Viewbag as parameter in SignalR Send

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send Viewbag in signalR Send method but I get empty value when It hit the server hub method please help.

Call to server in View:

```
       wall.server.send("@ViewBag.u",1,1,id,new Date(),false);
```

Hub:

```
  public void Send(object userId, int toWhomId, int likes, int postid, DateTime time, bool seen)
    {

   //
        //userId is emtpy here???


        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(userId, toWhomId, likes, postid, time, seen);
    }
```

Broadcast:

```
    $(function() {
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        wall.client.broadcastMessage = function (userId,toWhomId, likes, postid, time,seen) {
            var encodeduserid = $('<div />').text(userId).html();
            var encodedwhomid = $('<div />').text(toWhomId).html();
            var encodedlikes = $('<div />').text(likes).html();
            var encodedpostid = $('<div />').text(postid).html();
            var encodedtime = $('<div />').text(time).html();
            var encodedseen = $('<div />').text(seen).html();
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodeduserid
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedwhomid + '</li><li><strong>' +  encodedlikes
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' +encodedpostid + '</li><li><strong>' + encodedtime
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedseen  + '</li>');
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
  wall.server.send(ViewBag.u,1,1,id,new Date(),false);
```

You are in a code block already, no need for "@" or quotes.